# windsor.xml file of a website does not transform on CI server

Tags: castle-windsor, slowcheetah, xml-document-transform

My solution has a webproject and windows services.

website has a web.config and a windsor.xml and the service has a app.config and a windsor.xml file,which changes for each environment (Test,UAT,LIVE).

I can preview the transform locally on my PC for both websites and windows service (for web.cofig, app.config and windsor.xml).

The transform also works when I build/Rebuild/publish the files locally.

However, when I run on the CI server, services have their windsor.xml,appconfig transformed but website doesnt get the windsor.xml transformed (Although web.config is transformed).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember you may have to install/have slowcheetah on the server too. Also edit prj file referencing slow cheetah:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<SlowCheetahTargets Condition=" '$(SlowCheetahTargets)'=='' ">$(LOCALAPPDATA)\Microsoft\MSBuild\SlowCheetah\v1\SlowCheetah.Transforms.targets</SlowCheetahTargets>
</PropertyGroup>

...
<Import Project="$(SlowCheetahTargets)" Condition="Exists('$(SlowCheetahTargets)')" />
```

Comment: Yes. I have slowcheetah on the CI server. I also created a project folder with the targets (slowcheetah) to the solution. Instead of using the LocalAppdata (as per your suggestion), I used the project reference. Even this solution did not work.